# let $f \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and..

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck with the following problem that says :

> let $f \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ 
>   and $f''$ exist for all $x \in (a,b)$. Let $a \lt c \lt b$. 
>   **Prove that** there exists a point $\xi \in (a,b)$ 
>   such that $$f(c)=\frac{b-c}{b-a}f(a)+\left( \frac{c-a}{b - a} \right)f(b)+\frac12(c-a)(c-b)f''(\xi).$$

Can someone explain in details? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You are not new here -- you know the policy. What have you tried? You say you are stuck -- *where* are you stuck, and in attempting what?

Comment: Actually, I could not understand from where to start..If someone provides some hints ,I would be grateful..I was trying to use Lagrange's MVT but nothing substantial to put forward /share.

Comment: perhaps first make sure the statement is correct. It seems to me that it fails, e.g. for the constant 1 function on [0,2] with a=0, c=1, b=2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a typo wherein the term containing $f(b)$ should be $\left( \frac{c-a}{b - a} \right)f(b)$. Assuming so,

Define $P(x) = \left( \frac{b-x}{b - a} \right) f(a) + \left( \frac{x - a}{b - a} \right) f(b) + M(x-a)(x-b)$ on $[a,b]$, where $M$ is chosen so that $P(c) = f(c)$. Note that $P(a) = f(a)$ and $P(b) = f(b)$ also. So take $h(x) = f(x) - P(x)$ and use the mean value twice, noting that $h(a) = h(c) = h(b) = 0$, to determine $M$ as being $\frac{f''(\zeta)}{2}$ for some $\zeta$ between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Congratulations, you posted your first answer :)

Comment: Thank you! I hope to be useful..

Comment: yes, it took me a while to verify the details. I had realized there was a typo in the statement, but you went much further, to figure the correct question and its answer. So, there is $\alpha\in(a,c)$ and $\beta\in(c,b)$ with $h'(\alpha)=0=h'(\beta)$, then there is $\xi\in(\alpha,\beta)$ with $h''(\xi)=0$ (i.e $f''(\xi)=P''(\xi)$), and finally $P''(x)=2M$ is easy to compute.

Comment: @Mirko Can you kindly write a bit at the part where you applied MVT twice...to get the value of M.

Comment: @Mathslover As specified in the answer by Point, value of M is chosen so that P(c)=f(c). Then apply MVT twice. Then, unrelated to MVT, note that P(x) is a second degree polynomial, $P(x)=Mx^2+$ linear and constant terms, so $P'(x)=2Mx+$ constant, and $P''(x)=2M$ (for every $x$). In particular, $f''(\xi)=P''(\xi)=2M$. Note that $M$ was determined by the equation $f(c)=P(c)=$ $(\frac{b-c}{b-a})f(a)+(\frac{c-a}{b-a})f(b)+M(c-a)(c-b)$